# Is string comparison a constant cost?

Tags: ruby, big-o

Say I want to compare two strings, str1 and str2, for equality.

```
p str1 == str2
```

What is the complexity of the comparison operation in big O notation? Is it O(1)?

How about in other programming languages?

Comment: Don't just spam in a hundred of these questions. They're way too broad. This is trivial to [Benchmark](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) if you're concerned about performance.

Comment: Cleary the answer is O(n). Awesome.

Comment: Benchmarking is the concern since all the theory in the world means nothing when it comes to how Ruby actually behaves in practice. See [this list of examples](https://accidentallyquadratic.tumblr.com) where a reasonable assumption like that is completely wrong. Recently `reject!` was discovered to be inadvertently quadratic.

Comment: @tadman: that's a nice collection, thanks :)

Comment: @tadman One does not design an algorithm without an idea of it's theoretical cost. If you want to make another point, fine.

Comment: @tadman see my comment on the accepted answwer for another counter-intuitive benchmark(like) result

Comment: There's nothing wrong with asking theoretical questions in general, it's just that Stack Overflow is not about theoreticals, it's about specific, concrete programming problems, primarily those that can be solved with code. If you're asking about this on a theoretical/algorithmic level there's the [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com) site specifically for that. This question is not bad, it's just in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's O(N) in the worst case for me. You have a loop that checks each character in both strings. It's O(1) in some cases:

- they are the same reference
- they have different lengths
- the parameter object is not a string (note that that code is syntactic sugar for `str1.==(str2)`

Comment: in ruby, if the strings have different lengths, it still runs in O(n) time because ruby's implementation manually counts each character to find the string length. this is not the case for languages like java, which calculate string length once and store it in a variable.

Comment: @eiko as tadman says, benchmarking is important; and often counter-intuitive: http://codepad.org/pBu8Vdr3 . Ruby does _not_ seem to count each char every time.

Comment: @steenslag the implementation of str.== doesn't use str.size, it uses RSTRING_LEN to count the length of the string in c.

Comment: though i'm running a benchmark now and maybe RSTRING_LEN is constant time anyway? my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, test for equality is not O(1). If `str1` and `str2` point to the same object, then this can short-circuit as an *identity* test, which is O(1). (also some other cases, as pointed out by @ursus)

> How about in other programming languages?

Pretty much the same. Fundamentals don't change from language to language.